# Null pointer error when requiring @sap/hdbext in cds application with node

Tags: node.js, hana, cds

I want to use `@sap/hdbext` to call stored procedures from Hana DB. When I require the library in a const I get this error `libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type lttc::null_pointer Abort trap: 6`
What could the issue be? The dependencies are properly installed. Could it be something related to `xcode`?